# asp.net get debug stacktrace in browser

Tags: asp.net

I have a debug=true enabled deployment of my website on a server somewhere.  When I open it in a browser on the server, I get a stacktrace for my errors.  When I navigate to that page from another machine, I get squat.  How do I enable the stacktraciness for remote machines?

**EDIT**

stacktrace:[image]

squat (as in diddly squat):[image]

**TO RECREATE**

Create a vanilla Single Page App in Visual Studio and migrate everything to your database, web deploy that to Windows Server server somewhere with debug=true, attempt to debug connection string woes, fail as browsing the site from localhost on the server gives different behavior than browsing the site from an external machine.

Comment: Can you clarify what "squat" is?

Comment: As in "diddly squat", I think. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=diddly%20squat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is by design, so that the internals of your program don't get displayed to users - who might be frightened by them and think they have broken the internet - and malicious individuals who might use the information to try and hack at your data (e.g. if it exposes info about the database). It enables you instead to display a user-friendly error message of your choice.

However, if you want to override this feature in your non-live environments to make testing easier, modify your web config as follows, to set "customErrors" to "Off":

```
<system.web>
...
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
...
</system.web>
```

More info is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx

I would strongly advise you never to do this in a live environment. Instead, handle exceptions and log them to your server's event log, so you can trace any issues.

Comment: I have two websites running on the server, one is available publicly, one is available on the internal network.  I am using the internal network one for debugging, but I'd rather not have to RDP into the server to debug it.  This is just what I needed, thanks much.  Bonus points if there is an option to wrap this into my deployment process without having to add and delete lines every time...

Comment: use config transforms in Visual Studio. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Awesome.  You get free (gratis) beer if you're ever in Atlanta.